# Where can I find a list of Google print parameters

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-api

I am trying to write scripts to automate creating a PDF from a range of cells in Google Sheets.  I can't find a list of the print parameters for Google Print.  Where can I find these?

I've found the following parameters:
'size':       // paper size. 0=letter, 1=tabloid, 2=Legal, 3=statement, 4=executive, 5=folio, 6=A3, 7=A4, 8=A5, 9=B4, 10=B
'fzr':        // repeat row headers
'portrait':   // false=landscape
'fitw':       // fit window or actual size
'gridlines':  // show gridlines
'printtitle': // Show title
'sheetnames': // Show sheet name
'pagenum':    // Do not include page numbers
'top_margin', 'bottom_margin', 'left_margin' and 'right_margin'

I need to know what the parameter for setting the custom scale to 80%.

Comment: Is Google Print even a thing anymore?

Comment: The options to print in Google Sheets are Fit to Width, Fit to Height, Fit to Page, and Custom Number.  After selecting Custom Number you can specify the % to scale the image by on the page.  I'm looking for the parameter to use to specify that % scaling value.